# Converting characters to integer in memory [hypothetical]

Tags: c, computer-science

"Garbage" values are determined from previous programs to my knowledge. For examples if variable x = 10 and you terminate the program, then 10 is still stored at the address of x, but your access to it is lost. Hence, if in a new program you were to have an integer generate coincidentally at that same address it should generate 10 as its "garbage" value.

[mockup notes i made on the topic out of curiosity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Eb9p.jpg)

If you have a string of characters in succession which are all equal to NULL, they would each be stored as 0.

So, if in a new program you were to generate an integer at the starting address of that first character, what would its garbage value be? I have reason to believe it would be 0, but I'm unsure as to why exactly. Would it add each ascii value together to get a number, would some sort of binary conversion occur?

I recognize many compilers will auto initialize variables to zero, but some do not and create wildly interesting "garbage" values

Comment: The value of that integer would be the value of the first 4 or 8 bytes from that memory address, if it's all zero, integer would be zero.

Comment: Garbage values are determined by _nothing at all_, they're _garbage_. It could be previous programs, your own local stack frame changing, or Gary in accounting sticking his finger in the RAM. Text literals are usually stored in the data/text sections of the PE you build, and not something you'd really overwrite. What do you mean by "generate an integer at the starting address of that first character"? If your string is init'd to null chars, it would (as a c-string) simply terminate at the first `\0`. If you put an int at the start manually, it'd print the ASCII value of that int.

Comment: In general, if you're running a "hosted" program under a proper operating system, uninitialized memory starts out containing 0, *not* whatever the previous program left lying around.  If Program B could inspect previous Program A's memory like this, it could be a big security hole.

Comment: If you have some characters lying around in memory, and you later try to interpret them as an integer, the integer value you get depends on the characters' ASCII values, yes, although perhaps not in the way you might think.  For 32-bit little-endian integers, the string `abcd` would be interpreted as `0x64636261`, or decimal `1684234849`.

Comment: @Rogue: Re “Garbage values are determined by *nothing at all*, they're *garbage*”: That is generally false. So-called “garbage values,” more properly unspecified values, indeterminate values, or undefined behavior, are not determined by the C standard, and possibly also not by other documents, but that does not mean reasons for them do not exist. Computers are generally mechanical and operate in deterministic ways, aside from deliberate introductions of random behavior…

Comment: … In many, if not most, cases of “garbage values,” something is determining what they are, although amateur programmers might not know what those things are. And this fact is crucial; malicious actors **can** investigate what those things are and sometimes use them to exploit defects in programs. Also, experienced programmers can use knowledge of common causes of various otherwise unspecified behavior to help diagnose bugs. “Garbage values” are merely **undocumented** things, not things that are not determined in any way at all.

Comment: @animetibs Your worked-out "cats" example presumes big-endian [byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which is rare these days.  It's much more likely you'll get 1937006947.

Comment: Answers go in the answer space below. Please do not add "resolved" to your question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil perhaps I misspoke. I understand the values come from _something_, but attempting to diagnose what causes those values is a bit outside of the "mantra" for C-programming. It's better to not rely on those garbage values, and instead ensure your variables are initialized properly.

Answer (score 1):

> "Garbage" values are determined from previous programs to my knowledge.

No. In general-purpose multi-user systems, the operating system does not provide memory used by a previous process to a new process (except for intentionally shared data). When memory is provided to a new process, the operating system will ensure any potentially sensitive data is overwritten (usually with zeros). “Embedded” or special-purpose systems might behave differently.

> mockup notes i made on the topic out of curiosity
>
> if you took the space of a, b, c, & d and created an int, would it be 0? Why?

In C, each object except a bit-field are composed of a contiguous sequence of bytes. The contents of those bytes represent a value.

An `int` is an object. (An object is a selected region of memory whose contents may be used to represent values.) So the bytes in it determine its value. For integer types, C uses binary encodings to represent values. So, when all the bytes of an `int` are zero, the value represented is zero. (There are additional details about handling negative numbers, not addressed here.)

> So, if in a new program you were to generate an integer at the starting address of that first character, what would its garbage value be? I have reason to believe it would be 0, but I'm unsure as to why exactly. Would it add each ascii value together to get a number, would some sort of binary conversion occur?

This question is unclear. Characters are encoded as numbers. ASCII is commonly used as the encoding scheme. If you put characters in the memory of an `int`, the numbers that encode them will be in the bytes of the `int`, and they will represent whatever number their bits form in binary (possibly modified by interpretation of the sign bit). Note that some C implementations form the binary numeral for an `int` using its bytes in order from low address to high address, and use them in the other order (and other permutations are possible as well). So writing the same characters to an `int` in different C implementations may produce different values for the `int`.

> I recognize many compilers will auto initialize variables to zero, but some do not and create wildly interesting "garbage" values

It is rare that automatic objects (those defined inside functions without an explicit storage duration) or dynamic objects (those allocated with `malloc` or related routines) will be initialized to zero by a compiler except for debugging or security purposes, except that some of the allocation routines, notably `calloc`, including initialization.

Comment: Nit, encoding with basic ASCII should never implicate the sign-bit. 7-bit ASCII has max value of `127`. With extended-ASCII, (128-255), then yes, that's a possibility. Not 100% clear which is referred to in your ¶4.